# How do I select columns based on number of unique vales?

Tags: r, dplyr

My regression analysis is giving me trouble since one (or more) of my independent variables has only got one value. I haven't got the time to check the number of factor levels for 100+ variables, so I would just like to exclude all variables with only one value from my dataset.

How would I go about doing this?

I tried `df<-df%>%select_if(length>1)` and `df<-df%>%select_if(length()>1)`, but neither of these seems to work....

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made-up data

```
df <- data.frame("a" = sample(1:100, 10), 
                 "b" = sample(1:100, 10),
                 "c" = rep(42, 10),
                 "d" = sample(LETTERS, 10))
```

function to determine if not unique

```
not_unique <- function(x) length(unique(x)) != 1
not_unique(df$a)
not_unique(df$c)
```

Select columns desired

```
df <- df %>% select_if(apply(df, 2, not_unique))
```

Comment: In good old base R: `df <- df[sapply(df, not_unique)]`

Comment: Marking this as answer since I can fully understand the code despite my meager understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a `data.table` solution

`dt[,.SD,.SDcols = dt[,lapply(.SD,uniqueN)]>1]`

Answer (score 2):

in Base-R

```
df <- df[sapply(sapply(df,unique),length)>=2]
```

or

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))>=2]
```